# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1047 const err = new Error(message);

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

After installing nodejs on my windows 10 machine, when I try to use npm, I get this error

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1047
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module '../package.json'
 Require stack:
  - C:\Users\Mfoniso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
  - C:\Users\Mfoniso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1047:15)
     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:893:27)
     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:19)
     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
     at createEnginesValidation (C:\Users\Mfoniso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:7:15)
     at module.exports (C:\Users\Mfoniso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:78:27)
     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mfoniso\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:2:25)
     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:14)
     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1280:10)
     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1089:32) {
    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    requireStack: [
     'C:\\Users\\Mfoniso\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js',
     'C:\\Users\\Mfoniso\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'
    ]
  }

Node.js v18.14.0
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled but this issue still persist

Comment: Yes, I deleted the npm folder and reinstalled npm

Answer (score 3):

It look's like there is a missing file, the package.json, in the npm installation. The issue could be due to the corruption in the npm. You can try to re-install the npm:

1. Delete the existing npm folder located at `C:\Users\Mfoniso\AppData\Roaming\npm`.
2. Run this command to re-install the npm: `npm install -g npm`

If the issue still persists, you can just uninstall **both** Node.js and npm and re-install Node.js again.

Answer (score 0):

Code: `MODULE_NOT_FOUND`, you need install the module...

```
npm I cjs
```

Or:

```
npm i cjs@latest
```

If you intalled the module, erase